# MATLAB: "Scroll" through several lines to be plotted

Tags: matlab, plot, line

I'd like to do the following:

I have about 200 datasets which I'd like to plot in a figure. The complete data `alldata` roughly looks like:

```
x1 y1 ones(length(x1),1)
x2 y1 2*ones(length(x2),1)
x3 y3 3*ones(length(x3),1)
...
xN yN N*ones(length(xN),1)
```

whereas xi/yi are vectors of the same length. Let's call the third column `flag`. 
I always want to plot the lines in the figure where the flag is 1/2/3. I do this by selecting them one after the other (simply via `data = alldata(find(alldata(:,3)==1/2/3 (in 3 steps)), [1, 2])`) and plotting them via `plot(data(:,1), data(:,2))`.

But because there are so many other lines to be plotted, thus I *somehow* (I'm looking for a quick and easy way to do this) want to have the possibility to always ONLY show let's say the next 5 lines plotted and then somehow be able to scroll through and always show the next 5 or the previous 5 lines depending on which action I take.

Do you know any *easy* way to do this quickly? Do you know any toolbox or so, didn't find anything on the matlab file exchange?
I know certainly how to code it myself: I'd introduce a slider and depending on the slider position I'd always plot the lines with the flag `3+(i-1)*5` to `3+i*5` into a plot.

But maybe you know something quicker/easier :)

**EDIT**: thinking about it now after having written this post, it may even have been quicker to really do this GUI with a simple slider and a callback function myself as it's probably to specific to have a quick solution in the file exchange!? Thanks though!!

Comment: I think this may be a tad localized... and frankly I am having a hard time understanding your `flag` format (are there any typos in your code around `x3 y3 2*ones(length(x3),1)`?). GUI, slider, callback sounds like the best option. Maybe write your own answer and collect some points for accepting it...

Comment: the first dataset has the flag=1, the second flag=2 etc. As I didn't want to note this all down, I wrote `N*ones(length(xN),1)` as this will automatically add the flag with the number N into `length(xN)` rows in the matrix. Just to not have to write down all the example data... ;-)

Comment: I would suggest putting things into a cell array - then you don't have to do strange stuff with flags, but just look at the index of the cell. Might keep the code fractionally cleaner. And yes, you do have a typo `2*` should be `3*` apparently.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see it, yes it should be! Yeah cell-arrays might be handy too, but the data comes from a different source which I can't change and I think I keep on working with it like it is so far then changing the structure. But thanks for the idea, I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: In such a case I often plot into different figure windows, and then "scroll" by switching to the correct window. :-)

Comment: If the datasets themselves are fairly large and you want it to be quick, plot your 5 lines, keep the handles, then in your callback when you're selecting a new subset just update the `XData` and `YData` properties of the line objects. This is usually considerably quicker than a new plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the plot browser mode you can select multiple lines at a time and click the check box to display or not display the lines.

I believe you can select blocks of lines and then check their boxes together. This would mean you could view the 5 lines at a time you mention with only 3 or 4 mouse clicks. This GUI tool can be very helpful for interactively picking through plots of large data sets.

The specification for this tool is given [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotbrowser.html)

Comment: Sorry, I initially said the plot editor, but this is something else. These tools can be brought up using the command plotbrowser. I don't know if there is more functionality to this command. You might also search the file exchange for scripts which use this command and improve it.